# fastify-mongoose doesn't work, node.js and fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, loading, fastify

```
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path');
const fastify = require('fastify')();
const fastify_static = require('fastify-static');
const fastify_autoload = require('fastify-autoload');
const fastify_mongoose = require('fastify-mongoose');
const fastify_env = require('fastify-env');

let PORT;
let uri;

fastify.register(fastify_env, {
    dotenv: true,
    schema: {
        type: 'object',
        required: ['MONGO_URI', 'PORT'],
        properties: {
            MONGO_URI: {
                type: 'string',
                default: ''
            },
            PORT: {
                type: 'string',
                default: ''
            }
        }
    }
}).ready(err => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    PORT = fastify.config.PORT;
    uri = fastify.config.MONGO_URI;
})

fastify.register(fastify_static, {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
})

fastify.register(require('point-of-view'), {
    engine: {
        ejs: ejs,
    },
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'view')
})

fastify.register(fastify_autoload, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'Logic/Routes'),
})

fastify.register(require('./Logic/Plugins/cache'))

fastify.register(fastify_mongoose, {
    uri: uri
})

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await fastify.ready();
        await fastify.listen(process.env.PORT);
        console.log('Listening on port: ', PORT);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}

start();
```

Error: Error: `uri` parameter is mandatory
at D:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Antonio\Work\GitHub\NextLevel\src\main.js:30:15

The problem is with fastify-mongoose, or probably with fastify-env. I explain: if i write directly the URI in the URI parameter, it works. But using environment variables no..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dotenv, because you should, I don't advise you to put passwords in your code or access to your APIs.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

let's remember that when we started

```
 start()
```

we starting fastify and dotenv has to be invoked, otherwise process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE will not be included

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

fastify.register(fastify_mongoose, {
uri: uri
})
uri here is undefined. it will executed before uri = fastify.config.MONGO_URI;
Should Use code Below

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true
})
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path');
const fastify_static = require('@fastify/static');
const fastify_autoload = require('fastify-autoload');
const fastify_mongoose = require('fastify-mongoose');
const fastify_env = require('@fastify/env');
require("dotenv").config();
let PORT;
let uri;

fastify.register(fastify_env, {
  dotenv: true,
  schema: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['MONGO_URI', 'PORT'],
      properties: {
          MONGO_URI: {
              type: 'string',
              default: ''
          },
          PORT: {
              type: 'string',
              default: ''
          }
      }
  }
}).ready(err => {
  console.log(fastify.config,'fastify.config')

  if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
  }
  PORT = fastify.config.PORT;
  uri = fastify.config.MONGO_URI;
  
})

fastify.register(fastify_static, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
})

fastify.register(require('@fastify/view'), {
  engine: {
      ejs: ejs,
  },
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'view')
})

// fastify.register(fastify_autoload, {
//   dir: path.join(__dirname, 'Logic/Routes'),
// })

// fastify.register(require('./Logic/Plugins/cache'))

console.log(uri,'uriuriuriuriuri',process.env,'env')
fastify.register(fastify_mongoose, {
  uri: process.env.MONGO_URI
})

const start = async () => {
  try {
      await fastify.ready();
      await fastify.listen(process.env.PORT);
      console.log('Listening on port: ', PORT);
  } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
  }
}

start();
```

**strong text**